# EF Core with Mysql not scaffolding BIT(1) to Boolean

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to generate DB classes from the existing database (DB first) through. Net core CLI.

The DB was perfectly working with EF5 and .net4.5 but after migrate to EF core the bit(1) field is not scaffolding as bool instead it is generating as short.

Also tried with TinyInt(1) but no luck.

Technology Stack -
.Net core - 2.2
MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore (8.0.15)
MySQl Connector Net 8.0.13
innodb_version  8.0.13

Comment: Your problem sounds like this known bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94687. Use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql instead.

Comment: Yes, It was me who created that bug But no one replied So I reached out here and yes it is working fine with Pomelo.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to add this packages from Nuget: 
**MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore**   
**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design**

 
then run this command :

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=mypass;database=sakila" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir model -f
```

if this solution still not working try this solution : 
https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already tried with the first approach and it generates "short". I guess it could not be possible without Pomelo help.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify default type mappings to overcome the issue.

```
opts.UseMySql(
     connectionString,
     builder => builder.DefaultDataTypeMappings(m => m.WithClrBoolean(MySqlBooleanType.Bit1)))
.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
```