# How to generate property type bool from database with Entity Framework Core Database First

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am using MySQL 8.0 with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.

I have a table say:

> user(gender tinyint(1))

I have also tried bit(1), doesn't work either.

I want to have the Gender property in the mapped Class User to be type **bool**

I have gone through heaps of articles saying:

> set TreatTinyAsBoolean to true in connection string.

But how can I do it when I use Entity Framework Core Database First approach?

Here is my command to scaffold the database:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=mypws;database=mydatabase;treattinyasboolean=true;" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -o Models -f
```

No matter what the value for TreaTinyAsBoolean is (true or false), the generated property is always set to byte.

Comment: Is there any reason why it's not just a `BIT`?

Comment: as I tried bit, it is then converted to short, instead of bool. I can see why you are saying bit, as I used bit as my 1st choice because of the MS SQL treats bit as bool.  @JamesS

Comment: `TINYINT(1)` is the right column type in MySQL for `bool`. This sounds like a bug in MySQL EF.Core: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55491298/ef-core-with-mysql-not-scaffolding-bit1-to-boolean https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94687. Try using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql instead.

Comment: You are right~!  I figured it out by reading Pomelo 's readme and found the Scaffolding command line at the end of the page which saved me ~!!

Comment: So what was the solution? I'm having the exact same issue. @Franva